# Fundamental group of lens space

Tags: algebraic-topology

It's direct to find the fundamental group of lens space by using more advanced tools like covering spaces and theory of group actions.

But is there any way to show it using Van Kampen's theorem?

Comment: ["lens space"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably comes under "more advanced tools", but it does use van Kampen.

The lens space $L(p,q)$ can be realized by attaching two solid tori $D^2\times S^1$ along their boundary, via the homeomorphism that sends a meridian of the boundary torus of one of the solid tori to a curve on the boundary torus of the other that winds $p$ times around the longitude and $q$ times around the meridian. This is called a "Heegaard splitting" of $L(p,q)$ and is detailed nicely in Rolfsen's *Knots and Links*, Chapter 9B.

From this construction, the fundamental group can be calculated directly using van Kampen's theorem. The detail of how to do so is given in Hempel's *3-Manifolds*, Chapter 2.